# How to Install and configure shibboleth SP in windows8?

Tags: saml-2.0, shibboleth, service-provider

I have a custom IDP,i need to create SAML request from Shibboleth SP and fetch back the SAML Response and process it in Shibboleth SP.

I followed the documentation given by shibboleth for SP 2.5.6 installation for windows but found it is not clear.

[https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/Installation][1]

Can someone share links or posts where Shibboleth SP installation and configuration is done Step by step and easy to follow.

I have downloaded and installed the Shibboleth SP 2.5.6 for windows, but unable to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have to use Service Provider

Use [testshib](http://testshib.org) to test your app, it gives too much ease.

Follow the steps

1. download and instal sp on your machine
2. include shibboleth's configuration into your apache 
   2.1. into httpd.conf file add include "PATH/opt/path/etc/apache22"(if  version is apache2.2, otherwise appropriate)
3. in apache22.config file add the location you want to secure - it would be /secure  bydefault
4. in your shibboleth2.xml file (in etc folder) put your entity id(application defaults element), ex https://mywebsite.com/shibboleth - this can be anything, not neccessary a real path
5. put entity id of your idp in sso element, in case of testshib it would be https://idp.testshib.org/idp/shibboleth
6. in the metadata provider put idp's metadata uri to your idp's metadata urn, incase testshib it would be http://www.testshib.org/metadata/testshib-providers.xml
7. Download your metadata from https://mywebsitehost.com/Shibboleth.sso/Metadata - here mywebsitehost would be a real host and rest path will be automatically configured by shibboleth - this path will download your sp's metadata file
8. Upload your metadata file to testshib via register

You are ready to go. Go to https://mywebsitehost.com/secure and you should be redirected to idp to authenticate.

**NOTE**: Make sure you have a domain name configured with ssl(https)

Comment: i installed shibboleth sp in my machine.For verifying the installation i ran https://localhost/Shibboleth.sso/Status and it shows 404 error. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35939752/how-to-resolve-404-error-in-shibboleth-service-provider?noredirect=1#comment59614732_35939752