# How to resolve 404 error in Shibboleth Service Provider?

Tags: saml-2.0, shibboleth, service-provider

I have installed the Shibboleth SP[2.5.6 latest] in my Windows Server R 2012.I followed the links :

[Shibboleth Installation](http://www.itcs.umich.edu/itcsdocs/s4388/)

I verified the installation and ran this sitelink -https://localhost/Shibboleth.sso/Status

It throws ERROR.

> HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
>   The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Comment: More important is login flow. Are you able to redirect to idP and come back with successful authorization?

Comment: Akshay only if installation is successful we can proceed to configure and use it. after configure only i can make saml request to idp.

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to, the default site with id '1' may be in stopped state. Restart the default site and check.